# Mining sequences from data frame rows

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, arules, traminer

long time answer-seeker, first time question-asker. I have an R data frame that is a single column, 267,000 rows with 17 factors, like so:

```
regions
VE
PU
PR
DE
NU
AD
DE
NO
AD
```

I'm attempting to extract these as column sequences, with lengths of 2 and 3, then move down by 1 row and repeat until the end. repeats and order present. I want to take the above, and make it look like this:

```
s1   s2
VE   PU
PU   PR
PR   DE
DE   NU
NU   AD
AD   DE
DE   NO
```

I've tried using packages like TraMinEr and ArulesSequences, but I can't figure them out. I think it's because my sequences are purely states, there's no temporal information attached, not even in the source dataset. I also tried making my own iterator scripts, but I couldn't successfully. I've googled endlessly, and I'm just at wits end. I don't know how to do this. the eventual goal is to match the outputs with a 2 or 3 permutation data frame, and binarize matches with a 1, 0 for no matches, and process that x49 into a new data frame.

I'm no expert in programming or R, just a novice user. does anyone know a script or package that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically want to do is assign `regions` without the last observation to `s1` and `regions` without the first observation to `s2`. You don't necessarily need extra packages for that. There are several approaches:

**1) Using the `head` and `tail` functions**

With these you can get vectors without the last observation (`head(column, -1)`) or without the first observation (`tail(column, -1)`).

Using:

```
new.df <- data.frame(s1 = head(df$regions,-1), s2 = tail(df$regions,-1))
```

will thus get you:

> ```
> > new.df
>   s1 s2
> 1 VE PU
> 2 PU PR
> 3 PR DE
> 4 DE NU
> 5 NU AD
> 6 AD DE
> 7 DE NO
> 8 NO AD
> ```

If you want three columns, you could do:

```
new.df <- data.frame(s1 = head(df$regions,-2), 
                     s2 = head(tail(df$regions,-1),-1),
                     s3 = tail(df$regions,-2))
```

which results in:

> ```
> > new.df
>   s1 s2 s3
> 1 VE PU PR
> 2 PU PR DE
> 3 PR DE NU
> 4 DE NU AD
> 5 NU AD DE
> 6 AD DE NO
> 7 DE NO AD
> ```

**2) basic subsetting**

As an alternative to the `head` and `tail` functions, you could also use basic subsetting:

```
new.df <- data.frame(s1 = df$regions[-nrow(df)], 
                     s2 = df$regions[-1])
```

**3) using the `embed`-function**

```
n <- 3
new.df <- data.frame(embed(df$regions, n)[,n:1])
names(new.df) <- paste0('s',1:n)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > new.df
>   s1 s2 s3
> 1 VE PU PR
> 2 PU PR DE
> 3 PR DE NU
> 4 DE NU AD
> 5 NU AD DE
> 6 AD DE NO
> 7 DE NO AD
> ```

**4) using the `shift`-function from the `data.table`-package**

The `shift` function from the `data.table` package might also be an option:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
new.dt <- na.omit(dt[, .(s1 = regions,
                         s2 = shift(regions, 1, NA, 'lead'),
                         s3 = shift(regions, 2, NA, 'lead'))])
```

And instead of `na.omit`, you could also use `rowSums` on `is.na`:

```
new.dt <- dt[, .(s1 = regions,
                 s2 = shift(regions, 1, NA, 'lead'),
                 s3 = shift(regions, 2, NA, 'lead'))]

new.dt[rowSums(is.na(new.dt))==0]
```

Comment: This worked. Made me think more about my data as sets too. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Managed to complete the binarisation too.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `transmute` and `lead` in package `dplyr`:

```
df1 <-read.table(text="regions
VE
PU
PR
DE
NU
AD
DE
NO
AD",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% transmute(s1=regions,s2=lead(regions)) %>%na.omit

  s1 s2
1 VE PU
2 PU PR
3 PR DE
4 DE NU
5 NU AD
6 AD DE
7 DE NO
8 NO AD
```

If you wanted sequences of 3, you could add another columns with `lead(regions,2)`

```
df1 %>% transmute(s1=regions,s2=lead(regions),s3=lead(regions,2)) %>%na.omit
  s1 s2 s3
1 VE PU PR
2 PU PR DE
3 PR DE NU
4 DE NU AD
5 NU AD DE
6 AD DE NO
7 DE NO AD
```